# issue with TextBlock Underline

Tags: uwp-xaml

I have below Xaml code, am trying to underline the textblock content based on bool condition.When condition is true It works as expected (underline is visible)but when the condition is false underline still persists(Underline should not be visible when the condition is false)

```
<TextBlock Text="Name" TextDecorations="{x:Bind Model.NameError, Converter={StaticResource TextUnderlineConverter}, Mode=OneWay}"
```

Converter Code

```
public class TextUnderlineConverter : IValueConverter
    {
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
        {
            if ((bool)value)
                return TextDecorations.Underline;
            else
               return TextDecorations.None;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Venkat Thank you for your feedback. It's a known issue. The relevant team has been investigating this issue.

Current there is a workaround, you could set `TextDecorations` for [`Run`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.documents.run) node that under the `TextBlock`.

```
<TextBlock>
    <Run Text="Test Hello" TextDecorations="{x:Bind Flag, Converter={StaticResource ConverterText},Mode=OneWay}" />
</TextBlock>
```

Answer (score 0):

Bug in UWP as in Xaml below:

```
            <TextBlock>
                <Run  Text="Decorations can be toggled on and off"/>
            </TextBlock>

            <TextBlock Text="Decorations will not toggle off"/>
```

It is the same issue if you code the TextBlock in C#

```
    TextBlock textBlock = new TextBlock { FontSize = 18.0 };
    textBlock.Inlines.Add(new Windows.UI.Xaml.Documents.Run { Text = "This text will not stick on text decoration." });

    TextBlock textBlockBad = new TextBlock
    {
        FontSize = 18.0,
        Text = "This text will not enable the TextDecorations to be turned off"
    };
```